# Common lisp macro not calling function

Tags: common-lisp, lisp-macros

I am working on a complicated macro and have run into a roadblock.

```
(defmacro for-each-hashtable-band (body vars on &optional counter name)
  `(block o
     (with-hash-table-iterator (next-entry ,on)
       (destructuring-bind
            ,(apply #'append vars)
            (let ((current-band (list ,@(mapcar #'not (apply #'append vars)))))
              (for (i 1 ,(length (apply #'append vars)) 2)
                (multiple-value-bind
                      (succ k v) (next-entry)
                  (if succ
                      (progn
                        (setf (nth i current-band) k)
                        (setf (nth (+ 1 i) current-band) v))
                      (return-from o nil))))
              current-band)
          ,@body))))
```

im getting "Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION NEXT-ENTRY {100229C693}>"
i dont understand why next-entry appears to be invisible to the macro i have created.

I've tried stripping down this to a small replicable example but i couldnt find a minimal scenario without the macro i created where next-entry would be invisible besides this scenario no matter what I tried, i've always managed to find a way to call next-entry in my other examples so im stumped as to why i cannot get it working here

I've tested the for macro ive created and it seems to generally work in most cases but for some reason it cannot see this next-entry variable. How do i make it visible?

Comment: ,(next-entry) evaluates at macro expansion time. But there is no such operator at macro expansion time. The macro is trying to create code, which then AFTER macro expansion has such an operator via the with-hash-table-iterator macro. That's too late. If you want to call an operator during macro expansion, then this operator needs to be defined then and not in the generated code.

Comment: `,(next-entry)` should be `(next-entry)` without the unquote to be in the same level like the expression at the beginning defining `next-entry`.

Comment: Like always when programming a macro, you should ask yourself what exactly the code should be after the expansion. And check it with `macroexpand-1`. Then, you will see most of the mistakes. `(macroexpand-1 '(here the macro-call with some arguments)`

Comment: both `,(next-entry)` and `(next-entry)` yield the same error, the problem is that the code doesn't seem to be able to access functions introduced by defun, flet, labels, etc. only those introduced by defvar, let, let*, and the like

Comment: (edited answer to fix `,(next-entry)` to `(next-entry))` though the exact same problem happens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are multiple places where the macro generates bindings in a way that is subject to [variable capture (pdf)](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/331/resources/lisp/onLisp/09variableCapture.pdf).

```
(defmacro for-each-hashtable-band (body vars on &optional counter name)
  `(block o ;; VARIABLE CAPTURE
     (with-hash-table-iterator (next-entry ,on) ;; VARIABLE CAPTURE
       (destructuring-bind ,(apply #'append vars)
           (let ((current-band ;;; VARIABLE CAPTURE
                   (list ,@(mapcar #'not (apply #'append vars)))))
             (for
                 (i ;;; VARIABLE CAPTURE
                  1 ,(length (apply #'append vars)) 2)
                 (multiple-value-bind (succ k v) ;;; VARIABLE CAPTURE
                     ,(next-entry) ;;; WRONG EVALUATION TIME
                   (if succ
                       (progn
                         (setf (nth i current-band) k)
                         (setf (nth (+ 1 i) current-band) v))
                       (return-from o nil))))
             current-band)
         ,@body))))
```

A simplified example of such a capture is:

```
`(let ((x 0)) ,@body)
```

Here above, the `x` variable is introduced, but if the code is expanded in a context where `x`is already bound, then `body` will not be able to reference that former `x` binding and will always see `x` bound to zero (you generally don't want this behavior).

#### Write a function instead

Instead of writing a big macro for this, let's first try understanding what you want to achieve and write instead a higher-order function, ie. a function that calls user-provided functions.

If I understand correctly, your function iterates over a hash-table by *bands* of entries. I assume `vars` holds a list of `(key value)` pairs of symbols, for example `((k1 v1) (k2 v2))`. Then, `body` works on all the key/value pairs in the band.

In the following code, the function `map-each-hashtable-band` accepts a function, a hash-table, and instead of `vars` it accepts a size, the width of the band (the number of pairs).

Notice how in your code, you only have **one loop**, which builds a band using the hash-table iterator. But then, since the macro is named `for-each-hashtable-band`, I assume you also want to loop over all the bands. The macro `with-hash-table-iterator` provides an iterator but does not loop itself. That's why here I have two loops.

```
(defun map-each-hashtable-band (function hash-table band-size)
  (with-hash-table-iterator (next-entry hash-table)
    (loop :named outer-loop :do
      (loop
        :with key and value and next-p
        :repeat band-size
        :do (multiple-value-setq (next-p key value) (next-entry))
        :while next-p
        :collect key into current-band
        :collect value into current-band
        :finally (progn
                   (when current-band
                     (apply function current-band))
                   (unless next-p
                     (return-from outer-loop)))))))
```

For example:

```
(map-each-hashtable-band (lambda (&rest band) (print `(:band ,band)))
                         (alexandria:plist-hash-table
                          '(:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4 :f 5 :g 6))
                         2)
```

**NB. Iterating over a hash-table happens in an arbitrary order, there is no guarantee that you'll see the entries in any particular kind of order, this is implementation-dependant.**

With my current version of SBCL this prints the following:

```
(:BAND (:A 0 :B 1)) 
(:BAND (:C 2 :D 3)) 
(:BAND (:E 4 :F 5)) 
(:BAND (:G 6))
```

#### Wrap the function in a macro

The previous function might not be exactly the behavior you want, so you need to adapt to your needs, but once it does what you want, you can wrap a macro around it.

```
(defmacro for-each-hashtable-band (vars hash-table &body body)
  `(map-each-hashtable-band (lambda ,(apply #'append vars) ,@body)
                            ,hash-table
                            ,(length vars)))
```

For example:

```
(let ((test (alexandria:plist-hash-table '(:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4 :f 5))))
  (for-each-hashtable-band ((k1 v1) (k2 v2)) test
    (format t "~a -> ~a && ~a -> ~a ~%" k1 v1 k2 v2)))
```

This prints:

```
A -> 0 && B -> 1 
C -> 2 && D -> 3 
E -> 4 && F -> 5
```

#### Macro-only solution, for completeness

If you want to have only one, single macro, you can start by inlining the body of the above function in the macro, you don't need to use `apply` anymore, but instead you need to establish bindings around the body, using `destructuring-bind` as you did. A first draft would be to simply as follows, but notice that this is not a proper solution:

```
(defmacro for-each-hashtable-band (vars hash-table &body body)
  (let ((band-size (length vars)))
    `(with-hash-table-iterator (next-entry ,hash-table)
       (loop :named outer-loop :do
         (loop
           :with key and value and next-p
           :repeat ,band-size
           :do (multiple-value-setq (next-p key value) (next-entry))
           :while next-p
           :collect key into current-band
           :collect value into current-band
           :finally (progn
                      (when current-band
                        (destructuring-bind ,(apply #'append vars) current-band
                          ,@body))
                      (unless next-p
                        (return-from outer-loop))))))))
```

In order to be free of variable capture problems with macros, each temporary variable you introduce must be named after a symbol that *cannot* exist in any context you expand your code. So instead we first unquote all the variables, making the macro definition fail to compile:

```
(defmacro for-each-hashtable-band (vars hash-table &body body)
  (let ((band-size (length vars)))
    `(with-hash-table-iterator (,next-entry ,hash-table)
       (loop :named ,outer-loop :do
         (loop
           :with ,key and ,value and ,next-p
           :repeat ,band-size
           :do (multiple-value-setq (,next-p ,key ,value) (,next-entry))
           :while ,next-p
           :collect ,key into ,current-band
           :collect ,value into ,current-band
           :finally (progn
                      (when ,current-band
                        (destructuring-bind ,(apply #'append vars) ,current-band
                          ,@body))
                      (unless ,next-p
                        (return-from ,outer-loop))))))))
```

When compiling the macro, the macro is supposed to inject symbols into the code, but here we have a compilation error that says *undefined variables*:

```
;; undefined variables: CURRENT-BAND KEY NEXT-ENTRY NEXT-P OUTER-LOOP VALUE
```

So now, those variables should be fresh symbols:

```
(defmacro for-each-hashtable-band (vars hash-table &body body)
  (let ((band-size (length vars)))
    (let ((current-band (gensym))
          (key (gensym))
          (next-entry (gensym))
          (next-p (gensym))
          (outer-loop (gensym))
          (value (gensym)))
      `(with-hash-table-iterator (,next-entry ,hash-table)
         (loop :named ,outer-loop :do
           (loop
             :with ,key and ,value and ,next-p
             :repeat ,band-size
             :do (multiple-value-setq (,next-p ,key ,value) (,next-entry))
             :while ,next-p
             :collect ,key into ,current-band
             :collect ,value into ,current-band
             :finally (progn
                        (when ,current-band
                          (destructuring-bind ,(apply #'append vars) ,current-band
                            ,@body))
                        (unless ,next-p
                          (return-from ,outer-loop)))))))))
```

This above is a bit verbose, but you could simplify that.
Here is what the previous `for-each-hashtable-band` example **expands into** with this new macro:

```
(with-hash-table-iterator (#:g1576 test)
  (loop :named #:g1578
        :do (loop :with #:g1575
                  and #:g1579
                  and #:g1577
                  :repeat 2
                  :do (multiple-value-setq (#:g1577 #:g1575 #:g1579) (#:g1576))
                  :while #:g1577
                  :collect #:g1575 into #:g1574
                  :collect #:g1579 into #:g1574
                  :finally (progn
                            (when #:g1574
                              (destructuring-bind
                                  (k1 v1 k2 v2)
                                  #:g1574
                                (format t "~a -> ~a && ~a -> ~a ~%" k1 v1 k2
                                        v2)))
                            (unless #:g1577 (return-from #:g1578))))))
```

Each time you expand it, the `#:gXXXX` variables are different, and cannot possibly shadow existing bindings, so for example, the `body` can use variables named like `current-band` or `value` without breaking the expanded code.

Comment: so is there actually no way to do this with a macro? ive made some various changes my original code, but i think the reason why it was failing was that functions introduced by flet, labels, etc. are for some reason invisible to backquote or eval, this includes the iterator function introduced by with-hash-table-iterator

this can be seen from this quick example
(labels ((x()))  (let ((y nil)) (declare (special x y))  (eval `(progn (princ ,y) (princ ,x)))))

here there's no problems with y but x can't be declared special. It works if x is a lambda in a let however

Comment: (1) indeed, `eval` evaluates code in the null lexical environment, meaning the code you evaluate does not have access to the bindings in the code that calls evals (which is good); (2) you can write a macro that does what you want, but you need to introduce fresh symbols in the generated code to avoid variable capture, so you need to call `gensym`, I'll edit the answer